# Power BI Report Builder Count IF Expression

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I'm trying to create a count if calculation in powerbi report builder, previously I used the following logic to do this in power bi desktop but this does not transfer across to report builder;

```
MthMinus1LicStaffCnt>10 = CALCULATE (
COUNTROWS( 'Query1' ),
FILTER ( Query1, Query1[MthMinus1LicStaffCnt] >=10)
)
    / 
  COUNTROWS ( Query1 )
```

In report builder I have used variations of the following expression;

```
=IIf(Fields!MthMinus1LicStaffCnt.Value >= "10", Sum(Fields!MthMinus1LicStaffCnt.Value), 0 )
```

But it generates the following error:

> The expression used for the calculated field 'test' includes an
> aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function.
> Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions
> cannot be used in calculated field expressions.

Any ideas how to implement this in report builder, the basic logic is to count a field if it is >= 10

Thanks
Blowers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little fuzzy on the Power BI function but I think you just need to put your aggreagate around the IIF:

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!MthMinus1LicStaffCnt.Value >= "10", Fields!MthMinus1LicStaffCnt.Value, 0))
```

This will check each row and return the value if it's over 10 or zero if it's not and then sums them all together.

Previously the IIF was checking one row and then getting the sum of all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this out but it generates the error message again;                                                                                                                                                  
The expression used for the calculated field 'test' includes an aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.
----------------------------
The definition of the report '' is invalid.
----------------------------

Comment: @Blowers Sorry - I forgot about the calculated field issue. You shouldn't use the SUM in the calculated field but rather use it in the table or text box where you want the value. You can either use this expression where you want the value or SUM the calculated field.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you Hannover! (great name btw)